# How can I disregard whether commas exist in a string with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query for values such as:

```
AVOCADOS, GRANDPAS-HASS 70CT  23#
```

...which may be stored without a comma, such as:

```
AVOCADOS GRANDPAS-HASS 70CT  23#
```

I want to disregard whether the comma exists or not, as long as the rest of the varchar value is identical. How can I query for a commaized value and get back both records containing that identical value, but also records that are identical except for the lack of the comma?

IOW, with the following query:

```
select bla from unitproducts WHERE Description = 'AVOCADOS ABUELOS-HASS 70CT  23#'
```

...I want to get 'bla' for records with both of these descriptions:

```
AVOCADOS GRANDPAS-HASS 70CT  23#
AVOCADOS, GRANDPAS-HASS 70CT  23#
```

I could run the query twice, if the first one returns no records, inserting a comma before the first space in the string, but I'm hoping there's a more 'elegant' approach that wouldn't require such a workaround.

Can this be done with "LIKE"? If so, how?

### UPDATE

It ended up that in my case I couldn't change the SQL itself (it is in a shared StoredProc), so I bandaided the code with this:

Former code:

```
bool isContractItem = IsContractItem(desc);
```

Current code:

```
bool isContractItem = IsContractItem(desc);
if (!isContractItem)
{
    desc = Decommaize(desc);
    isContractItem = IsContractItem(desc);
}

. . .

private string Decommaize(string stringWithComma)
{
    return stringWithComma.Replace(",", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Is this for ad hoc searching, or for when hitting an index is important?

Comment: it can be done witl LIKE using the underscore as awilcard for a single character  e.g. "WHERE Description LIKE 'AVOCADOS_ ABUELOS-HASS 70CT  23#'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a bit overkill since it may make just as much sense to just clean the data in the first place, but to make the search hit indexes, you can add the stripped field as a computed column and add an index on it;

```
ALTER TABLE unitproducts ADD desc_search AS REPLACE(description, ',', '');
CREATE INDEX ix_desc_search ON unitproducts(desc_search);
```

Then you should be able to just efficiently do;

```
SELECT bla 
FROM unitproducts 
WHERE desc_search = REPLACE('AVOCADOS ABUELOS-HASS 70CT  23#', ',', '');
```

Since the replace is just performed once on your string instead of also once per row to find a match, the search can use the index on the computed column to find your row.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
WHERE REPLACE(string1, ',', '') = REPLACE(string1, ',', '')
```

or for your specific example

```
WHERE REPLACE(Description,',','') = 'AVOCADOS ABUELOS-HASS 70CT 23#'
```

If you want to put "identical" records first in the result list you can also do

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Description='AVOCADOS ABUELOS-HASS 70CT 23#' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Note that neither method is sargable, so any query that does not limit data in some other way will likely do a full table scan.

Comment: I just voted yours, as you were 30 seconds faster than me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(100)='AVOCADOS GRANDPAS-HASS 70CT  23#';
DECLARE @str2 VARCHAR(100)='AVOCADOS, GRANDPAS-HASS 70CT  23#';

SELECT CASE WHEN REPLACE(@str1,',','')=REPLACE(@str2,',','') THEN 'ident' ELSE 'not ident' END
```

Answer (score 1):

The undescore in LIKE matches a single character.

```
SELECT bla 
FROM   unitproducts 
WHERE  Description LIKE 'AVOCADOS_ ABUELOS-HASS 70CT  23#'
```

[LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)